# How to execute a shell automation task?

Tags: bash, shell

In my home directory, I am having a script named `blabs` and I am passing a file as argument to this bash script like:

`./blabs \home\blabs\someFileName`

And this will give the results and everything is working fine.

Now I want to automate this task.I have 1000 files in a directory named `2016_10_1` located in home directory.So I want to pass each file as argument to the script.

I wrote a small snippet but it is not working properly.Can anyone help me with this

```
for i in (find /home/blabs/2016_10_1/ -type f);do "./blabs /home/blabs/2016_10_1/$i";done
```

Error Log:

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: you're missing a `$` to execute your `find` command: `for i in $(find ... )`

Answer (score 2):

Find has a built in execute on all found items. So this command will do what you are looking for.

```
find /home/blabs/2016_10_1/ -type f -exec /path/to/blabs {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

> See [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), why you should *NOT* parse output of `find` or `ls` in a for loop.

You use a process substitution syntax(`<()`) like below,

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r file
do
    /path/to/blabs "$file"
done< <(find /home/blabs/2016_10_1/ -type f)
```

The output of `find` is fed one line at time to the while loop, and the script `./blabs` executed on it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Oliv suggests, you may quick fix this by adding a `$`:

```
for i in $(find . -type f); do echo "THIS $i"; done
```